# Why does this procedural material distort at larger scale?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, procedural

I'm trying to learn more about procedural textures, and I created a concrete texture loosely following a youtube tutorial. At the scale I worked at, it looked just like I wanted. However, when I tried to apply the texture at larger scales, pale stripes appear on the surface. It does not seem to be related to the mesh, but to something inherent in the texture.

[image: The texture on smaller scale objects]
[image: The texture when applied on larger scale objects]

.blend example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kInkSXyzw1h-rgxYs9mBZdOlMhCCb83c

Could someone tell me what went wrong here and how  can fix it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is this musgrave texture :

[image]

I set the dimension to 0.4 and the patterns disappeared. Try never going so low with the dimension parameter because it causes repeating patterns.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Gorgious, wow, all those nodes!!! Someday, your computer will commit suicide.

Comment: To be faire it was taken from the OP's blend file, but with complicated procedural materials it can get quite overwhelming

Comment: "All those nodes"? Have you seen the nodes required for the top "Nodevember" entries? :)